# Show correct stacktrace in karma tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, karma-runner

**Prerequisites**

- Typescript
- Karma / Jasmine
- Webpack

**Application**

I have simple TypeScript application. Also set of *.ts tests and karma framework to run this tests. Transpiling with Webpack.

Here is part of karma configuration:

```
    ...
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine','sinon'],

    files: [
        'src/test/spec/**/*.ts'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
        'src/**/*.ts': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
    },

    webpack: {
        debug: true,
        devtool: 'inline-source-map',
        module: webpackConfig.module,
        resolve: webpackConfig.resolve
    },

    webpackMiddleware: {
        quiet: true,
        stats: {
            colors: true
        }
    }
    ...
```

And webpack configuration

```
   ...
   resolve: {
       extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.tsx', '.jsx', '']
   },
   module: {
       loaders: [{
               test: /\.tsx?$/,
               exclude: /node_modules/,
               loader: 'ts-loader'
           }
       ]
   }
   ...
```

Everything works fine, tests are written using TypeScript, PhantomJS is used as headless browser. It works.

**Problem**

But I experiencing problems with investigating failed tests, because stack trace written to console is incorrect - it always points to the test source file even problem occurred in other place(s).

As an example - I'm sharing my console output after karma launcher

```
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new vRef(this)')
        at src/test/spec/validations/required.ts:1764
        at DataBase (src/test/spec/validations/required.ts:1690)
        at src/test/spec/validations/required.ts:50
        at http://localhost:9880/context.js:151
```

where 'src/test/spec/validations/required.ts' - it's my test file, but stacktrace truly goes through 3 different files.

How to fix output data to point correctly to failed place? Would be very appreciated if anyone can share with me my config or setup problems.

Comment: I have tried karma-sourcemap-loader and karma-source-map-support with no joy. I just get a stack trace in the test entry file, on line numbers that don't exist (compiled lines).

Comment: Yes, the same issue :(

Comment: try to add chrome in the browsers array in karma.conf. I experienced that chrome has the most detailed/correct stacktrace.